# Downloading image with requests results in unrecognized file format

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download a couple of images in my script, but even though the images seem to download, they seem to be corrupted or unrecognized. And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
This is the part of my code:

```
tshirt_pic = requests.get("https://www.innovasport.com/medias/playera-nike-jordan-jumpman-is-CJ0921-011-1.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1MDg4MnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g3ZS9oMjgvOTc1OTk4MjY4MjE0Mi5wbmd8NTZlODA5YzhmMDZmOGMyYTBkODliMGM3NGE0NGE0YzBlOThhMTAzM2ZmMWMyODM4M2ZjNTVjNmNmZWExM2VkNw").content
with open('my_pic.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(tshirt_pic)
```

If I copy the image link in my browser, it opens correctly. But when using my script, the png donwloaded just can't be opened... Do you guys know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `print(tshirt_pic[:10])` to see how it looks.

Comment: Use a text or hex editor to look into the file. How does it begin?

Comment: Begins: `b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting [<Response [403]>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Doing something like this is probably the easiest:

[image: curl]

Then translate it with something like: https://reqbin.com/req/python/c-xgafmluu/convert-curl-to-python-requests

Comment: CURL request as pre-formatted from the browser works fine, so you may be able to get around it by sending the request with the correct header.

Comment: Ah, I see so it's a question of permissions... what do you mean with correct headers?

Comment: Added some additional resources:

Comment: You should be able to use the same header for multiple images of the site :')